# Azure function with Azure storage - Function throwing exceptions

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure function in our Pre-Prod environment which is working fine in accessing the storage and doing the required operations.

Now I am trying to implement the same in Prod environment, Prod is in different Azure Account. I replicated each and every step from Pre-Prod to Prod. But things are not working here as the function is throwing below error.

> "Error: Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable. Click here for details
> on storage configuration."

I referred to several documentations in checking the priority settings to rectify this but couldn't able to do it.

Note: I am a developer and had good experience in GCP, I am completely new to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when Azure functions app lost its connections to Storage Account that supports blob, queue and table storage. This is because Functions relies on Azure Storage for operations such as managing triggers and logging function executions

Below is one of the reason which might happen:

- Deleting the storage account.

And below are some of the settings that are added:

- AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage -- true
  When this app setting is omitted or set to `false`, a page similar to the following example is displayed in response to the URL `<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net`.

You can check other related webjob storage settings from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage)